# TFS CI build trigger include variable

Tags: variables, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to use a variable as build trigger? I've tried and the build doesn't get triggered. If I remove the variable and insert a value, the build gets triggered as expected.

Aren't variables allowed here? `$(Mapping.ServerPath)` is set to `MyRepo/Branches/MyBranch`. `$/MyRepo/Branches/MyBranch` triggers the build correctly.

[image]

Comment: What's the detail requirement that you need to use variable in path filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. And why should they?

The specified path results in a poll action being performed on the static path.
You can [use wildcards](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers) if needed.
The build should trigger on a change, hence CI trigger.

Making the path a variable, when would you provide it?
If it's just keeping a static value elsewhere, why not fill it in?
If you want to provide the path when calling the build. 
Then you don't intend to use the CI option as intended?

Comment: Ye, thanks for confirming my thoughts on that topic. I'm just a user of a build template. I just wanted to ensure that this is not my mistake :)

Comment: Our branching strategy uses a new branch (Fork for Git guys) for every iteration and every release. We have dozens of builds, one for each microservice and web portal. It is best for us to use a single variable where we can change the path to the current iteration or release branch in one place instead of in each of the dozens of builds.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported.

There is a user voice that you can follow: [Allow Variables in Repository, variables and triggers Tab.](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/14131002-allow-variables-in-repository-variables-and-trigg)

Comment: The link returns 404

Answer (score 0):

We have a microservice architecture with dozens of builds, it makes sense to be able to use a variable that we can update when we start our next iteration. With our branching strategy we have a new branch for each sprint and for each release. Changing the CI trigger in every build every couple weeks is inefficient.

We are using on premise TFS2018 and from everything I've seen this is not supported.